# how to retrieve inserted checkbox values in checkbox on asp.net page load?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have 5 checkboxes in webform and textbox1...

when i search the record using the date specified in textbox1

when i enter 11-Dec-2010 in Textbox1 and click on submit button then checkbox1, checkbox2, and checkbox3 will be disabled and unchecked .....

and after tat when i type 13-Dec-2010 in  Textbox1 and click on submit button then checkbox1, checkbox4, and checkbox5 will be disabled and unchecked .....and all the checkbox of 11-Dec-2010 will be enabled for 13-Dec-2010

I M CURRENTLY WORKING IN ASP.NET (VB)

My Datbase structure :

```
ID              Name                 Seats                 Date
1               Sumit                1,2,3                 11-Dec-2010
2               Mili                 1,4,5                 13-Dec-2010
```

**Example of this is that site have a look to know more : what i want :**

http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SeatSelection.aspx?rt=4034093&doj=28-Feb-2011&dep=05:00%20PM&showSpInst=false

Comment: We really need more of a question to work with.  Do you have some code currently?

Comment: Then are you trying to on Button click, search the database and retrieve what checkboxesare supposed to be disabled.  Then Disable and check said checkboxes?

Comment: retrieve all seats values from database for 11-Dec-2010 if i search for 11-Dec-2010 then checkbox of 11-Dec-2010 will be disabled and unchecked  on page load event ...

Comment: http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SeatSelection.aspx?rt=4034093&doj=28-Feb-2011&dep=05:00%20PM&showSpInst=false

Comment: You need to ask a question.  You are essentially saying "Give me code that does this".  I will not write your code for you, But I'm happy to answer questions and help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't giving us much to go on this is the best I can do for you:

In your OnClick code for the button put

```
if(TextBox1.Text == "11-Dec-2010")
{
   checkbox1.Enabled = false;
   checkbox1.Visible = false;
   checkbox2.Enabled = false;
   checkbox2.Visible = false;
   checkbox3.Enabled = false;
   checkbox3.Visible = false;
}
else if(TextBox1.Text == "13-Dec-2010")
{
   checkbox1.Enabled = false;
   checkbox1.Visible = false;
   checkbox4.Enabled = false;
   checkbox4.Visible = false;
   checkbox5.Enabled = false;
   checkbox5.Visible = false;
}
```

This will satisfy the requirement:

> when i enter 11-Dec-2010 in Textbox1
>   and click on submit button then
>   checkbox1, checkbox2, and checkbox3
>   will be disabled and unchecked .....
>        and after tat when i type 13-Dec-2010 in Textbox1 and click on
>   submit button then checkbox1,
>   checkbox4, and checkbox5 will be
>   disabled and unchecked .....and all
>   the checkbox of 11-Dec-2010 will be
>   enabled for 13-Dec-2010

If you can clarify your question I can provide a better answer.